# Can anyone explain what is the error in the following program?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Can anyone explain what is the error in the following program ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 10, b = 20;
  (a, b) = 30; // Since b is l-value, this statement is valid in C++, but not in C.
  printf("b = %d", a);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should post the message too

Comment: `(a, b) = 30;` - Why write this

Comment: `(a, b)` --> 20 , `(a, b) = 30;` --> `20 = 30` is not assignable.

Comment: Tagged "compiler-errors" but the error message is not shown. Why?

Comment: Huh? Why this edit? Don't change the question! Especially if it already has an answer...

Comment: Sorry, the question has been changed. I wanted to ask this question.

Comment: @user1178323: Never change the question after it has been answered. Ask a new one instead.

Comment: That's ridiculous. A very basic question, covered by every C tutorial, poorly worded, not reacting to the comments (compiler error?), after it has an answer changing it to something entirely different, with the same problems. What's this? Testing how much trash can be posted here while there are still people willing to help you?

Comment: `*(&a, &b) = 30;printf("b = %d", b);` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't allow multiple assignment like that, set each variable to 30 in a different statement.

Comment: Or write `a = b = 30;`